# Schibboleth with Sitecore 7

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, sitecore, membership-provider

Has anyone tried to configure SiteCore 7 to use Schibboleth?

Would this be better accomplished using a Membership Provider or using a Virtual User?

Does anyone have access to any examples?

Thank you all so much!

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin Buckley has a good article on how to do something similar with federated identity using WIF and virtual user in Sitecore.

http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-the-windows-identity-foundation/

This is a good starting point for an approach to take when integrating other security providers, hopefully some use to you :)